# The usage of notation $\lim a_n = 1^+$ for "$a_n$ approaches $1$ from above"

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

I have a seemingly trivial problem that I cannot seem to figure out.

Imagine I want to prove that the series of $n$ does not converge, and for that I use the d'Alembert rule (yes it's ridiculous but it's for my example) I learned in school that if $(U_n)$ is a strictly positive sequence and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n} =1^{+}
$$

then the series of $(U_n)$ is divergent.

So here is my problem: what's the result of $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n+1}{n},$$

is it $1$ or $1^{+}$ ?

(Because if the limit is one we can't conclude and if the limit is $1^{+}$ we can conclude that the series of $n$ is convergent.)

Comment: Um, what does $1^+$ mean in this context?

Comment: And if you want to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n$ doesn't converge, then it's much easier to observe that every term is $\ge 1$ from $n=1$ onwards, so the partial sums are at least $n$ which diverges to infinity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The whole expression $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right) =1^{+}$ means that the LHS equals $1$ and that the sequence $\left( \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is larger than $1$ for large values of $n$.

Comment: @Shadock I just read your question on its entirety. The comment above should answer your question.

Comment: @Henning Makholm That's why I precise this is rediculous to do that and it's not my problem here... :) Well for me the notation $1^{+}$ is when the ratio approach 1 but not touch it.

Comment: You may be confusing with the (common) notations: $\lim_{x\searrow 1} \equiv \lim_{x\overset>\to 1} \equiv \lim_{x\to 1^+}$ for the [one sided limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) ?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: I'm not english and my english is very poor so I try to think how you can understand what i don't understant :)

Comment: @Shadock Well, do you understand my first comment here?

Comment: A bit but just a bit ... ^^

Comment: @Shadock I answered the question. I tried to be as clear as possible. If I'm not answering your question, consider adding a french version of the problem to the question so people can try to help you.

Comment: In the future, when addressing a user, type `@usersname message`, for example, to address me, type `@GitGud whatever`. This will send me a notification.

Comment: @GitGud whatever :P

Comment: @Shadock It worked :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right) =1^{+}$$ is an abbreviation of

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right) =1\land \exists p\in \mathbb N\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(n\ge p\implies \dfrac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\ge 1\right).$$

In view of this, applying this criterion to the series $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(n\right)$ should offer no problem.

Obviously $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{n+1}n\right)=1$ and setting $p=1$ it also trivially holds that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(n\ge 1\implies \dfrac{n+1}{n}\ge 1\right).$$

Comment: OK that's perfect ! :D

Answer (score 3):

The limit is equal to $1$,  $1^+$ just implies that the limit approaches $1$ from the positive side.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I don't vote down... :O

Comment: So if the limit is 1 in which case 1 is not the limit but 1+ ?

Comment: @Shadock I don't understand your comment, but it seems to me that you're misinterpreting the notation. The symbol $1^+$ is not an object by itself, it's not something that exists. You can make sense only of $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right) =1^{+}$, but not of $1^+$ by itself. The equal sign here is not an equality, it's an abbreviation for what I explained in my first comment to the question.

Comment: As explained by Git Gud, 1+ means the limit is greater than 1 and not that it is equal to 1+

Comment: Ok but I have four choices in my maths lesson, and this limit is one of the fourth so I don't understand what I have to do with this? [link](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/346087limite.png)

Comment: @sholaOtitoju OK so if the limit is greater than one there is no question beacause by the d'Alembert's rule if ratio>1 then the series is devergent.. isn't it? :/

Comment: yes, if it is greater than 1, then it is divergent.

Comment: I really don't understand :( maybe if you explain me with a picture ? And i don't know if you understand what i don't understand.. :/

Comment: I don't really get what you asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19837/discussion-between-shadock-and-shola-otitoju).